# Chef missing artifact, nested github dependency

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf

When using `chef exec berks install` I am getting errors relating to having a missing artefact.

My tree is
`a -> b -> c`. `b` and `c` are both hosted on github. `b` is able to install, but when trying to install from `a` I get the missing artefacts error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve recursive git cookbook dependencies with Berkshelf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603281/resolve-recursive-git-cookbook-dependencies-with-berkshelf)

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it where to get `b` and `c` from. Berksfiles, like Gemfile are not transitive. If you are trying to source from git, you'll need to add that to `a`'s Berksfile as well.